# Difficulty understanding what the (n-1) part refers to in a basic arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am 28 and learned no maths in school. I'm going back through and learning on my own time. I am up to arithmetic sequences. The general formula (according to Khan Academy) for a recursive arithmetic sequence seems to be:

a(1)=3
a(n)=a(n−1)+2

I have a basic understanding of the concept of a sequence, i.e. that it is describing a relationship between numbers that involves either repeated addition or subtraction (it may involve multiplication and division as well but I'm not sure as I'm not up to that).

I cannot understand what the (n-1) is. I get that the a(1) is the first term and that the +2 at the end is what gets added to the term each time. But what is the n-1. I know it refers to something along the lines of finding the term before the term, I think?

Cheers for any explanations or examples.

Comment: Your age and background are unimportant.

Comment: Just like we use $x$ to refer to non-specific number when we don't know which one we use $a_n$ to refer to one of the terms in some position but we don't know which position.  We call it the $n$th position.  So $a_{n-1}$ is the term in the position immediately before it.  And $a_{n+1}$ is the term in the position immediately after it.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence will be a bunch of terms:  $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,...... $ and we can refer to each term by its index.  The fifth term is $a_5$.  The $39$th term is $a_{39}$ and so on.

If we pick some arbitrary term but want to indicate it might be any term we can call it be an arbitrary index.  $a_n$ is the $n$-th term.  It could be the $512$th term, $a_{512}$ or it could by the $7,487$th term, $a_{7,487}$.  We don't know and don't care.  We are refering to a non-specific term.

We are refering to a term when we don't know what position it is in.  We say "let's call the position it is in: $n$".

Now, let's suppose I said "After picking that term look at the previous term"  or "look at the next term".  How can we refer to that.  We if our term was the $a_{512}$ then the previous term would be .... $a_{511}$.  And if our term was $a_{7,487}$ the next term would be .... $a_{7,488}$.

But how do we refer to it in general.  If our term was $a_n$ what is the term immediately before it.  Well, if this was the $n$th term, the one write before it is the $n-1$th term, $a_{n-1}$.

So in this case:

> $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2$

means.  "Pick any term.  It is equal to the term before it plus two".

So if the previous term $a_{n-1}$ was equal to $517$ then this term, $a_n$ will be equal to $519$.

So $a_1 = 3$ because we were told so.

And $a_2 = $ the previous term plus $2 = 3+2 = 5$.

And $a_3 = a_2 + 2 = 5 + 2 = 7$ and so on...

$a_4 = a_3 + 2 = 7 + 2= 9$ .....

Comment: Thanks very much for these helpful responses. This gives me a far better understanding of where the n-1 is coming from. I appreciate the time you all took to post. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions define values in terms of previous values.

In your case, the definition of $a$ says that the first value is $3$ and we get the $n$th value by adding $2$ to the previous value.

So

$a(2)=a(1)+2=3+2=5$,

$a(3)=a(2)+2=5+2=7$, etc.